AMM vs CLMM constant product?
From what I've researched and understood, AMM uses constant product curve for price. Does CLMM also use constant product formula within ticks (each tick seperately), the only difference is that the ticks in CLMM use ranges with their constant product formula... So if I would derive the token X and Y liquidities ("reserves") from the sqrtpriceStart and sqrtpriceEnd of a tick and pool liquidity, I would be able to replicate a graph showing the constant product curve just like in AMM using those 2 (xy=k)? Is my approach correct?

Yes, your approach is correct, as CLMM uses the constant product formula within each tick range, and you can derive token reserves from liquidity and price bounds to replicate a piecewise constant product curve.

how would i derive the reserve amounts, or simulate them, to then succesfully simulate a trade like in AMM - amountOut=(reserveOut×amountIn)/(reserveIn+amountIn)

To simulate a trade in CLMM, calculate reserves within the active tick using X=L√P and Y=L×√P, where L is the liquidity and P the price, then apply the constant product formula within the tick's range for the specified amount.

With P you are reffering to the current sqrt price, right? What if the current tick does not contain liquidity, so the swap jumps to the next one with liquidity, but since the current price is out of the new ticks range, one of the reserve would be 0, right? In that case i cannot simulate the swap using the constant product formula as in amm.

If the current tick lacks liquidity and the price moves to a new tick, reserves are recalculated based on the new tick's liquidity and price bounds, and swaps are simulated piecewise across active ticks using the constant product formula within their respective ranges.

I have the next initialized ticks sqrtPrice upper, sqrtPrice lower and tick liquidity. I'd like to get a "simulated" number of reserve amounts, so i can plug the clmm tick into AMM constant product formula amountOut=(reserveOut×amountIn)/(reserveIn+amountIn), and get the same result as if  iwas using Δx = L * (1 / √P_lower - 1 / √P_upper) , and other clmm formulas. I am sure it is possible to figure this out since both CLMM tick and AMM use the same constant product formula

Yes, it is possible because both CLMM and AMM use the constant product formula within their respective ranges.
